# Pandas groupby apply function with an array of functions

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, data-science, feature-engineering

I have a dataset like this (example purpose)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Store' : [100, 100, 100, 100, 101, 101, 101, 101],
    'Product' : [5, 3, 10, 1, 3, 11, 2, 5],
    'Category' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A'],
    'Sales' : [100, 235, 120, 56, 789, 230, 300, 35]
})
```

So it is like

```
Store   Product Category    Sales
100      5       A           100
100      3       B           235
100      10      C           120
100      1       A           56
101      3       B           789
101      11      A           230
101      2       C           300
101      5       A           35
```

Each store has some products and each product has some category. I need to find out the total sales for each store and percentage sales for each category in each stores. So result has to be something like this:

```
         total_Sales    Category_A  Category_B  Category_C
Store               
100       511            30.528376   45.988258   23.483366
101       1354           19.571640   58.271787   22.156573
```

(The category columns are in %)

Currently I am doing it like this:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Store']).apply(lambda x: x['Sales'].sum())
df1 = df1.to_frame()
df1 = df1.rename(columns={0 : 'Sales'})

def category_util(x, col, cat):
    total_sales = x['Sales'].sum()
    cat_sales = x[x[col] == cat]['Sales'].sum()
    if cat_sales == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return cat_sales*100/total_sales
df1['Category_A'] = df.groupby(['Store']).apply(lambda x: category_util(x, 'Category', 'A'))
df1['Category_B'] = df.groupby(['Store']).apply(lambda x: category_util(x, 'Category', 'B'))
df1['Category_C'] = df.groupby(['Store']).apply(lambda x: category_util(x, 'Category', 'C'))
```

`df1` is the desired output. It is working fine, but every `apply` function is sorting the grouping columns again and again and for a big dataset, **it is highly time consuming**. I want to do this in one function call. I tried something like:

```
df.groupby(['Store']).agg([lambda x: category_util(x, 'Category', 'A'),
                          lambda x: category_util(x, 'Category', 'B'),
                          lambda x: category_util(x, 'Category', 'C')])
```

But it fails with a `KeyError` for 'Sales`

```
pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: 'Sales'
```

**Any solution for this? Is there any way to use `apply` function with an array of lambda functions and calculate all the columns in one go? If it is not possible with `apply`, is it possible to do with `agg`?** It will really save me a lot of time. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `groupby` with `unstack`. Then we divide the sum over the `axis=1`:

```
dfn = df.groupby(['Store', 'Category'])['Sales'].sum().unstack(level=1)
total_sales = dfn.sum(axis=1)
dfn = (
    dfn.div(total_sales, axis=0)
    .mul(100)
    .add_prefix("Category_")
    .assign(total_sales=total_sales)
).rename_axis(columns=None)
```

```
       Category_A  Category_B  Category_C  total_sales
Store                                                 
100     30.528376   45.988258   23.483366          511
101     19.571640   58.271787   22.156573         1354
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is literally the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `pivot_table` and `unstack`

```
table = df.pivot_table(index=['Store', 'Category'], values=['Sales'], aggfunc='sum')#.unstack().add_prefix('Category_')
t_sales = table.sum(level=0)
table=table.div(table.sum(level=0)).mul(100).unstack().add_prefix('Category_')
table.assign(total_sales=t_sales).reset_index()
```

---

```
    Store   Category_Sales                          total_sales
Category    Category_A  Category_B  Category_C  
0   100     30.528376   45.988258   23.483366       511
1   101     19.571640   58.271787   22.156573       1354
```

---

Answer (score 2):

We can create two groupby objects (relatively cheap operations), and pipe a function that returns a dataframe, containing the total sum, and percentages:

```
group1 = df.groupby('Store')

group2 = df.groupby(['Store', 'Category'])

(df.assign(total_sales = group1.Sales.transform('sum'))
.groupby(['Store','Category'])
.pipe(lambda df: pd.DataFrame({"res" :df.Sales.sum()
                                        .div(df.total_sales.max())
                                        .mul(100), 
                               "total_sales": df.total_sales.max()}))
.set_index('total_sales', append = True)
.unstack('Category')
.droplevel(0, axis=1)
.add_prefix('Category_')
.rename_axis(columns=None)
.reset_index()
)


   Store  total_sales  Category_A  Category_B  Category_C
0    100          511   30.528376   45.988258   23.483366
1    101         1354   19.571640   58.271787   22.156573
```